# issues in Case and when Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about `Case` and `when` statements. I have a list of two transtypeid like 10 and 12.

I tried to take sale1 amount like if the transtypeid 11 has a sum amount !=0 means, I need to minus the amount with sum amount of transtypeid 10

I tried a lot but nothing worked.

I have these queries I tried

```
select 
    CT.CustomerCode, C.CustomerName,
    sale1 = case 
               when (ct.TransTypeID = 11) and (sum(ct.OVAmount  - ct.OVDiscount) != 0) 
                 then sum(ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount) - sum(ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount) 
                 else 0 
            end,
    C.CountryCode, C.CityCode 
from 
    CustomerTransactions CT
inner join 
    Customers C ON CT.CustomerCode = C.CustomerCode
where 
    ct.TransDate >= '2015-01-01' 
    and ct.TransDate <= '2015-12-31' 
    and ct.TransTypeID in (10, 11)
group by 
    ct.CustomerCode, c.CustomerName, c.CountryCode, c.CityCode
```

Comment: As I see it, sale1 is always 0.

Comment: hi ....i need to minus the amount from transtypeid 11 to transtypeid 10

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.  Also sum(ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount) - sum(ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount) might be mistyped. Is like 5-5 if you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand.  Could you provide some sample values and expected output? Here's a handy guide from the help pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It's better to not use [an inclusive upper bound with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Also, you _might_ get better performance by writing your sums as `SUM(ct.OVAmount) - SUM(ct.OVDiscount)`; it's usually better to do math/perform adjustments on the fewest values possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try calculate sale1 with this SQL code:

```
CASE WHEN 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ct.TransTypeID = 11
        THEN ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount
        ELSE 0 END) != 0
    THEN
        SUM(CASE WHEN ct.TransTypeID = 11
            THEN ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount
            ELSE O END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN ct.TransTypeID = 10
              THEN ct.OVAmount - ct.OVDiscount
              ELSE 0 END)
    ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you need. But I give it a try since you are in hurry.

Something like this, maybe?

```
select 
    CT1.CustomerCode, C.CustomerName,
    sale1 = 
    case 
        when ( sum(ct1.OVAmount  - ct1.OVDiscount) != 0 )
            then sum( ct1.OVAmount  - ct1.OVDiscount ) - sum( ct2.OVAmount - ct2.OVDiscount ) 

        else 
            0 
    end,
    C.CountryCode, C.CityCode 
from 
    Customers c
    Inner join CustomerTransactions CT1 ON ( CT1.CustomerCode = C.CustomerCode ) And ( ct1.TransTypeID = 11 )
    Inner join CustomerTransactions CT2 ON ( CT2.CustomerCode = C.CustomerCode ) And ( ct2.TransTypeID = 10 )
where 
    ( ct1.TransDate >= '2015-01-01' )
    and ( ct1.TransDate < '2016-01-01' )
    and ( ct2.TransDate >= '2015-01-01' )
    and ( ct2.TransDate < '2016-01-01' )
group by 
    ct1.CustomerCode,c.CustomerName,c.CountryCode,c.CityCode
```

Comment: Thanks for ur try......i tried that method already ......the prob is i have 33 record in transtypeid 10 and 900 records in transtypeid 11 ....now the result shown for only 33 records

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better to put as many conditions as possible as part of the join.  Oh, and don't use an inclusive upper bound with dates.  However, this version will give incorrect results due to multiplying rows in `CT1` by rows in `CT2`.  You'd need to complete the aggregate first.  On the plus side, that would make the grouping operator narrower....

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using CTEs:

```
with 
cte10 ( CustomerId, amount ) as ( 
    select 
        customerId, sum( amount ) as amount 
    from 
        CustomerTransaction 
    where 
        ( Type = 1 )
    group by CustomerId 
),
cte11 ( CustomerId, amount ) as ( 
    select 
        customerId, sum( amount ) as amount 
    from 
        CustomerTransaction 
    where 
        ( Type = 2 )
    group by CustomerId  
)
select 
    c.Id, c.Description,
    sale1 = 
    case 
        when ( cte10.amount <> 0 )
            then cte10.amount - cte11.amount 

        else 
            0 
    end
from 
    Customer c
    Inner join cte10 on ( cte10.CustomerId = C.id )
    inner join cte11 on ( cte11.Customerid = C.id )
```

[image]